# Predicting values using quantile regression

Tags: regression, cross-validation, least-squares, quantile-regression

I entirely rewrote the question, since it was marked as unclear.

Suppose I have a linear regression model $Y=b_0+b_1 X_i+\epsilon$ for a time series dataset that consists of $Y$ and $X$.

I can now estimate $b_0$ and $b_1$ for different quantiles of $Y$: $bq_0$ and $bq_1$

***Question 1***: I have estimated $bq_0$ and $bq_1$ for the 0.1-quantile. Inserting new data for $X_i$ into the estimated regression model gives me with the 0.1 quantile of the new $Y$. Is this correct?

***Question 2***: To my understanding, quantile regression estimates the quantiles conditional on the specific quantile of $Y$. Is there a way to estimate effects conditional on the quantile of $X$? If so, one could construct a regression model that automatically changes it estimators, if $X$ reaches specific values. For example if $X$ is above the median, $bq_1$ is 1. If $X$ is below the median, $bq_1$ is 0.5.

***Question 3***: How do you cross validate the result from a quantile prediction for a time series? In the case of OLS for example, you could just compare the actual time series for year X, with the one you predicted for the year X. So if I had predicted one value for each month, I could compare this with the actual value for each month and see if it matches. How would you do this in case of quantile regression? If I predicted the 0.1 quantile for this case, I would have 12 data points that would represent the 0.1 quantile of the predicted distribution. Comparing this with the actual data does not make sense in my eyes.

I am sorry for being a bit confusing first. That is probably due to my lack of understanding of the topic. I hope it is clear what I am asking now.

Comment: You can apply an estimated quantile regression to a new dataset in exactly the same way as an OLS regression. Of course the regressors should be semantically the same and measured in the same way in the training and the test dataset - but this applies equally to quantile and "normal" regression. Can you clarify what you are looking for? What is your original and new dataset?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. See the edit please. The data is semantically the same and measured in the same way in both datasets.

Comment: I mean I know I can just insert new data in a single quantile regression estimation. But that would not make any sense, because I am putting data into a model that is designed to explain just a part of it (a quantile).

Comment: Well, if you run a quantile regression for the 80% quantile, then feeding new data into the model will predict the 80% quantile for the new data. A quantile prediction is often very useful, and I have tried using quantile regression in exactly this way.

Comment: 0.1 refers to a proportion, not to a value of the response. E.g. 0.5 is the median. This value is known "beforehand", it does not depend on the response.

Comment: Alright thank you! Is there a way to reconstruct a time series via quantile regression? The thought I had in mind is that, when Y enters different "quantile regions", the effect of X on Y changes. I thought of some sort of dynamic approach that would automatically reflect those changing effects via switching estimated coefficients when Y enters different "quantile regions".

Comment: Maybe one more comment to clarify what I am saying: Suppose I have a time series that consists of 10 days and 10 data points. Now when estimating the 0.1 quantile I get the relationship between x and y, given y is within the 0.1 quantile - right? So when I have new data and insert it, I get what? A set of new Y values that reflects the above mentioned relationship. Those Y values are the 0.1 quantile of the new output. So far I hope this is correct. But how would I compare this to the old data? I dont have 10 data points to compare this with. The estimation is based upon only the 0.1 quantile.

Comment: Quantile regression will have the same problems with time series that OLS regression has. OLS regression is only predicting the mean.

Comment: I am sorry for being so unclear. I completely re-edited the question. I would be grateful for comments or even answer.

Comment: The b0 and b1 are parms of the OLS model, so the quantile-reg will have different parms... call them something else. Also, you don't obtain "different" parms for various quantiles of Y, the parms *predict* the quantiles.

Comment: Alright, I renamed then. And I understand that I dont get different parameters per se, but I do get different values of the parameters that explain the relationship between Y and X for different quantiles of Y.